# R Shiny DT datatable how can I change the selected class

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

Is there a way to change the class of the selected row/column/cell without having to use the "Select" extension?

**The problem:** when `style = "bootstrap"` is set, the class for the selected item is `class = "active"`. Because bootstrap themes usually set `active` to some sort of grey, DT must override bootstrap's `active` background color so it's not confused with the white/grey alternating row colors. Instead of overriding the color, I want to change the class from `active` to `info`. This way, any theme I choose will look nice and the selected row will not be confused with the not-selected rows.

Additionally, the blue that DT chose to override bootstrap's `active` background color makes the highlight of search terms look hideous. See the example. And the blue that DT chose for the `style="default"` does not always look good with the selected bootstrap theme.

BTW, I successfully changed the selected class to `info` using the "Select" extension and setting it in the options, but that presented other problems, mainly that I could not pre-select a row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dt <- data.frame(colA = sample(c("one","two"),10,replace=T), ColB = rnorm(10))

ui <- basicPage(
  DTOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$test_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(dt,
      style = "bootstrap",
      selection = list(mode = "single", selected = 1),
      options = list(searchHighlight = T, search = list(search = "o"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could overwrite the CSS of the class for the selected rows, copying the CSS properties of the **info** class. I may miss something, but I don't see any other convenient solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I hate to hard code CSS changes in an app, but like you, I don't see another convenient solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that tries to avoid dependencies on html/css structure written by DT package, which can change without notice. It uses `bs_add_rules()` to assign the theme's color to the variable `--dt-row-selected`. This solution works on bslib 0.6.1 and DT 0.32.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(bootswatch = "superhero") |>
    bslib::bs_add_rules("
    :root {
      --dt-row-selected: var(--bs-primary-rgb)!important;
    }"),
  DTOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris,
      selection = list(mode = "single", selected = 2)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```